# basic application of AWS SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to build a basic **Hello, World!** application using `AWS SNS` and `node.js`, I have written some very basic code and it's not working. My Code is given below:

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

 // aws configuration 
 var awsConfig = {
    'region': 'us-east-1'
 };

 if (process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY != undefined && process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY != null) {
    awsConfig.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
 }

 if (process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY != undefined && process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY != null) {
    awsConfig.secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
 }

 var sns = new AWS.SNS(awsConfig).client;

 console.log("sns : ", sns);  // here sns value is 'undefined'

 sns.createTopic({  // "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTopic' of undefined"
    'Name': 'sent-email'
 }, function (err, result) {

      console.log("some msg expecting........");
      if (err !== null) {
         console.log(util.inspect(err));
         return;
      }

      console.log(util.inspect(result));

  });
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChrisThompson no, there's nothing wrong with that syntax.

Comment: @ChrisThompson, not working, it's the same error

Comment: @user2013 please elaborate what you mean when you say "it's not working". When asking for help with an error you should post the actual error message, or the exhibited vs. expected behavior. Is the SNS topic not getting created? Is there an error message being printed?

Comment: @MarkB, It's the same error

Comment: Ah I see now, you put the error in the code as a comment. That's not exactly obvious.

Comment: @MarkB I suspected I might be wrong, hence the comment, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SNS.client` is undefined. Check [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html). You should just be doing this:

```
var sns = new AWS.SNS(awsConfig);
```